# How to find array coordinates with Mouse Listener

Tags: java, arrays, mouselistener

Instead of hard coding 64 buttons to create a board  did a 2D array and I need to get the `array coordinates`. This is the code I tried using and the error I got.

#### code:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        JButton[][] clicked = (JButton[][])e.getSource();
        int x = clicked.length;
        int y = clicked[0].length;
        board[x][y].setIcon(selected);
    }
```

#### Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to [[Ljavax.swing.JButton;
```

Comment: Presumably you are clicking one button at a time, not all 64 ? So why should the source of the click be an array?

Comment: ok that makes sense but how do  tell the array coordinate of the button i clicked. just to make sure i am not saying getX im saying I.E.[2][4]

Comment: You have two options: search for `clicked.equals( buttons[x][y] )` or create a `Map<JButton,XY> m` and call `m.get(clicked)`.

Comment: can you please provide an example coding of your solution in the answer. I have no idea how to use  `Map<JButton,XY> m` and per the first solution that would require hard coding 64 buttons which is what I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to not hard code each option use a `for loop` for the action listener and use variables.

#### Solution:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    JButton clicked = (JButton)e.getSource();
    for(int x = 0; x<8; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0;y<8;y++)
        {
            if(clicked == board[x][y])
            {
                occupied[x][y] = true;
                board[x][y].setIcon(selected);
            }
        }
    }
}
```